# Typescript: Cannot extend express request | client is missing in type Request

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

Im making and api and a had to give more properties do Request to get access of req.client, to check if the client is authenticated, and im getting the following error (please open i cant put images yet):

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7WSB.png) 
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODvYS.png) 
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KYQX.png) 
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yoFP.png) 
[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vScSp.png) 
[image6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOjuC.png)

this is the controller:

```
export class AuthMiddleware {
    async isAuthenticatedClient(req: GetClientAuthInfoRequest, res: Response) {
        const { token } = req.cookies

        if (!token) {
            res.status(401).send({
                message: "Faça login para acessar esse conteúdo"
            })
        }

        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "sgjlskdfghajhdfghsd") as JwtPayload;
        req.client = await prisma.client.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: decoded.id
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is the Express and Client interface (they are in different files):

```
import { Request } from "express"
import { Client } from "./Client.types"

export interface GetClientAuthInfoRequest extends Request {
    client: Client | null
}

export type Client = {
    name: string
    email: string
    password: string
}
```

this is the route where im getting the error:

```
router.route('/teste').get(authMiddleware.isAuthenticatedClient, authController.teste) // this route just return a simple message to test the middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file express.d.ts inside your types folder:

```js
declare module "express" {
    export interface Request {
        client: Client | null;
    }
}
```

and make sure that your "dev run command" has the `--files` flag:
package.json file:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --files src/index.ts",
}
```

Now you can use the regular Request type of express.
:D